# Unable to add a data series to an Excel chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I am struggling to add the new data series required to label the segments. I cant seem to add these in to the radar chart.

I want the segment labels to be A2:A9

Any suggestions?
[image]

Comment: Did U try,, Right click Graph, then Add New Series ?

Comment: That option doesn't come up :(

Comment: ,, Right click  chart and Select Data from menu, from popping out dialog, click Add button, then Edit Series,  specify the Series name and Series values , the OK.

Comment: @RajeshS The OP has already tried that in her screenshot.

Comment: @Burgi,, thanks for observation,,, this is the only possibility,, not sure that Y she is struggling !!

Comment: Thanks for your help! Got there eventually

Comment: Hi Ellen, please share what you did to get to the bottom of your problem to help others in this situation